# Cursor not centered on feature - OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Can anyone tell me why the cursor is not centered on the feature? This can be seen in the Overlay event of the map and even in the onClick event. We can only click on the element in a certain position, never in the center.

[image: er]

Comment: We are not using offset on map features

Comment: Can you give more details - i.e. snip of your code?